# The benches were sheltered beneath the stilts of a bamboo-walled hut

Tags: meaning-in-context

I came across a sentence like this -

> The benches were sheltered beneath the stilts of a bamboo-walled hut.

I know that **stilts** means **poles**. How benches should be sheltered beneath the poles?

Comment: Perhaps, it's something like this: http://homepage.ntlworld.com/sam.wane/beyondstafford/asia/hut.JPG

Comment: @DamkerngT. Then the use of **Beneath** should be wrong, is not it? More correct option would be **at the foot of**

Comment: Considering that *beneath* can mean ["directly under something or at a lower level"](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/beneath), I believe that *"benches beneath the stilts"* is not wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is an instance of hasty or careless writing. We often speak of a picnic or a path—or benches—*beneath* trees; the preposition is both conventional and proper here, because you are in fact beneath the canopy. I suspect that the same image is intended with *beneath the stilts*, with the benches beneath the floor of the hut among the stilts—and that the potential absurdity of the image never ocurred to the author.

The lesson is what I call the *Adamantine Law* of written English: “Anything which can be misunderstood will be.”

Answer (score 0):

The sentence does not necessarily indicate that the stilts are actually doing the sheltering, just that the benches that are being sheltered are beneath the stilts.